# Google Sign In Button error when trying to login

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have followed all the steps of the Firebase instructions for adding a Google Sign In Button. I have two problems when I open the app I have to wait a couple of minutes before pressing the Google button otherwise it gives me an error, after the first sign in if I try more still gives me the error.
(I added all the pods, all the app delegate function requested, the url in the target section of the app, the google.key-value list, and tried all possible solutions from other similar questions)
The errors I get are

> Optional(Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-5 "The user canceled the sign-in flow." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The user canceled the sign-in flow.})

Please if someone could help, cause I tried all stack overflow and google possibilities, and still not working.

Here is snippet of my code:

```
    import Firebase
    import GoogleSignIn


    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var googleButton : GIDSignInButton!
     viewDidLoad(){
     self.googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
     self.googleButton.style = .iconOnly
    self.googleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 120, y: 300, width: 75, height: 75)
    self.googleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(configureGoogleButton),        for: .allTouchEvents)
    
    
    self.view.addSubview(self.googleButton)

     }

      function configureGoogleButton(){

    //get client Id
    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else {return}
    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
       
    
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: self)
    { user,error in

        guard error == nil else {
            print("The app is not working")
            print(error)
            return }

         guard
           let authentication = user?.authentication,
           let idToken = authentication.idToken
         else {
           return
         }

         let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                        accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        
        self.googleCredential = credential
        print(user?.profile?.email)
        print(user?.profile?.name)
```

}

Here is part of the app delegate:

```
     import Firebase
      import UIKit
      import GoogleSignIn

    @main
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
    
    
}

// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}



   func application(
  _ app: UIApplication,
  open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey :         Any] = [:]
) -> Bool {
    
  var handled: Bool

  handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.handle(url)
  if handled {
    return true
  }

  // Handle other custom URL types.

  // If not handled by this app, return false.
  return false
}
```

}

Comment: You are not showing all relevant lines of code.  Start from the name of the class.

Comment: You don't have `GIDSignInDelegate` and `GIDSignInUIDelegate`.  Add them to your view controllers.  And set its delegate to self in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @ElTomato I can't find any GIDSignInDelegate in the library of the installed pods, and neither on the firebase or google doc says about any delegate